# Simple Product is not associated with configurable product in magento 2.2.5?

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.2.5, simple-product

I have Configurable product with 146 associated products.I want to add another associated product to configurable product.I am able to select the simple product but its not showing after save the configurable product.

Selected simple Product attribute set and configurable product attribute set both are equal and simple products have the selected configurable attributes also.

Please any one help?

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem (with grouped products).  I actually raised this as an issue on Github

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22887

Need to change php settings, in particular max_input_vars and restarting apache/php-fpm in order for the changes to take effect.

Note: the value needs to be in the 1000's

Comment: yeah already change the php settings but there is no change.Agian simple product is not associated with configurable product